# R - What is the proper way comment out a roxygen tag?

Tags: r, comments, roxygen2, roxygen

Say I want to comment out a `#' @export` tag - what is the documented way to do so?

Adding a `#` in front (as with standard R comments) doesn't seem to work: `##' @export foo` still leads to `export(foo)` in my `NAMESPACE` file.

Can I also block-comment out entire roxygen sections in RStudio?

Comment: I think you'll need to make a feature request at RStudio's site. FWIW, they're highly responsive.